# Gradle wrapper error in GitHub Actions: 'validateDistributionUrl' doesn't have a configured value

Tags: gradle, github-actions

I have a Gradle build that uses a gradle wrapper. I can build locally using Gradle 8.5 with the wrapper configured to 5.6.4. The first step is to run

```
gradle -b bootstrap.gradle
```

This was also run using GitHub Actions for my project. It seems like GitHub updated their Gradle version to 8.6, and now I'm getting this error in my GitHub build.

> A problem was found with the configuration of task ':downloadWrapper' (type 'Wrapper').
>
> - Type 'org.gradle.api.tasks.wrapper.Wrapper' property 'validateDistributionUrl' doesn't have a configured value.

What do I need to do to fix my build?

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same problem. I was able to fix it by adding `--validate-url` to the gradle command line:

```
gradle wrapper --gradle-version 7.6 --validate-url
```

Change the gradle version as appropriate for your project.